# What are the rules behind this translated phrase: "das, was ihr mich habt tun sehen"?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, word-order, past-participle

I came across this when reading the German translation of the Book of Mormon:

> Denn **das, was ihr mich habt tun sehen**, ja, das sollt ihr tun.

The English part reads:

> For **that which ye have seen me do** even that shall ye do.

There are a few things that I don't understand:

1. Why is "*sehen*" used here instead of "*gesehen*", the past participle?
2. Why isn't "*habt*" at the end of the phrase?
3. Why the accusative "*mich*" instead of "*mir*"?
4. Why is the preposition "*zu*" not placed before "*tun*"?

It's as if "*sehen*" were behaving as a modal verb, but even that doesn't explain everything.

If I were to translate the phrase with my own limited experience, I would write:

> Denn das, was ihr mir zu tun gesehen habt, ...

Why was this phrase translated as it is, and what would be the most common (or natural) German translation of the English phrase "*to see one do*", for example:

> The crime I saw him do

Comment: As for your last question, I would indeed say "Das Verbrechen, das ich ihn habe begehen sehen." No wonder you're having some trouble here - even for a native speaker, this construction is a bit complicated.

Comment: Is the complete sentence "Denn das, was ihr mich habt tun sehen, ja, das sollt ihr tun."? That sentence is not easy, but absolutely OK. Not very easy, to explain. One thing is very easy ;p "Mich" because you can ask: "Who have you seen?"//"Wen habt ihr gesehen?". That question shows that it is the accusative case. The others are a bit more complicated to explain.

Comment: Btw. you use "zu" like "to" in English. "He forced me to do..." - "Er zwang mich zu tun..."

Comment: @Em1 That makes sense. I guess I couldnt justify knowing whether "I saw him to do it" in german made better sense or not. For example, in English we wouldn't normally say something like "I imagined him do it" But you can say "I imagined him to do it," so I always thought to be safe that I always use "zu" whenever the verb isn't modal.

Comment: Side note: The sentence "The crime I saw him do" would be more natural "The crime I saw him doing". The former is an emphasis on the result, while the latter emphasizes the process. And I think that's what you most times want to connote, don't you? However, @HendrikVogt translation is fine either way, though not typically.

Comment: @Em1: So how would you typically say it?

Comment: @HendrikVogt Depends on. In colloquial I would rephrase it completely. E.g. "Das Verbrechen, bei dem ich ihn beobachtet/gesehen habe". But of course it needs much more context. The sentence sounds incomplete. However, if I have to keep the style of the original I would take your version.

Comment: @Em1: Yes, colloquially that sounds a lot better.

Comment: @Dougvj I changed your last question from "most correct" to "most common(or natural)", because it is hard to say what is the "most correct". There often a handful good translations, but you'll hardly decide which one is "most correct".

Comment: @Em1 Not to mention that there can be several ways of saying "to do" depending on context.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Welcome to GL&U!

Your sentence uses a double infinitive forming the perfect tense in a dependent / subordinate clause. That sounds kind of complicated, but break it down into its smaller parts and then put it back together (I did also find an English [page](http://www.dartmouth.edu/~german/Grammatik/perfect/Perfect.html) for you that further explains some of these peculiarities).

First, recognize that a subordinate or dependent clause can change the word order around. So, you want to start off by finding the **main verb** of the subordinate clause (which is "*sehen*"), and see that it uses a **helping or auxiliary verb** ("*habt*") to form the perfect tense (just find the verbs for now and don't worry yet about if it uses *ge-* or not, since it's your first go-over). Next, determine **who** it was that did the *sehen* (which is "*ihr*"). Then add **whom** *ihr* saw (which is "*mich*"), and finally tag on the **what** you all saw me **do** (the "*was*" and the "*tun*"), which refers back to the antecedent *das* from the preceding sentence, which was probably something like "*Tut das, was ihr...*"

Now I'll try to summarize what you are specifically asking.

1. When forming a double infinitive, the *ge-* is normally dropped and the infinitive form used, although it is technically possible to use the *ge-* form unless you're using modals (*wollen*, *mögen*, etc.), for example.
2. The auxiliary verb (*habt* in this case) must lead the verbs in a double infinitive construction.
3. The accusative *mich* is used because *sehen* is the main verb doing the action, and it requires accusative.
4. In a double infinitive construction, the *zu* is normally dropped.

This construction does behave this way with any type of auxiliary verb, whether modals or *haben* or whatever.

These are general rules, but I hope that helps get you going. Everyone feel free to point out anything I've missed with the grammar.

Comment: Excellent explanation. The link you sent hit it spot on: "The same is true of verbs of perception that take an infinitive without "zu." "Sie hört ihn singen" becomes "Sie hat ihn singen hören." and "In these cases, the double infinitive remains in the final position in dependent clauses, and the "haben" slips into the second-the-last place:" That's exactly what I was looking for. Well Done!

Comment: The ["Zwiebelfisch"](http://www.spiegel.de/kultur/zwiebelfisch/0,1518,632042-2,00.html) lists sentences where there even is a triple infinitive: *"Wir haben uns den Weg zeigen lassen müssen"*. ;)

Comment: I'm glad it all helped, Dougvj. Great addition, Takkat. :-)

Comment: And Takkat, you could even start that phrase with a "daß" to throw all the verbs together completely, lol. Bastian Sick is so great. :-)

Comment: *Wir hätten uns den Weg zeigen lassen können gewollt.* :-)